# Minimize distance given a few constraints

Tags: c, 2d

Say my start point is the origin on the x-y plane.

I'm only allowed to move in a certain way.
As in, someone tells me that my next move can only be a linear combination of 2 co-ordinate points.

My goal is, in as many moves as possible to find out the point which will be closest to the start point to which I can get to (except for the origin of course).

For example, say if I was told that the 2 points are a=(13,4) and b=(17,5).

Therefore the closest I can get to from the origin is (1,1). Which is got from 4a-3b.

I've written a programme for it. But according to me the logic is completely flawed.

However it outputs the correct answer for the few test cases that I've tried.

Here's my code

```
#include<math.h>
int sq(int a)
{
    return a*a;
}

int main(void)
{   
    int a,b,c,d,min=200000,i,j,n=100;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
    for(i=-100;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=-100;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(sq((i*a)-(j*c))+sq((i*b)-(j*d))<min)
            {
                min=sqrt(sq((i*a)-(j*c)))+sqrt(sq((i*b)-(j*d)));
            }   
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",min);
    return(0);
}
```

Feel free to give your inputs and if there's a better way to tackle the problem.

The answer that is being is outputted in the programme is |x|+|y|.

Comment: Are *a* and *b* always positive?

Comment: Also, are only integer solutions allowed?

Comment: No a and b need not only be positive and yes only integral solutions are allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do the math, you'll see that there is a simpler way to do your exhaustive search.

Let *l,m* be the coefficients of your linear combination (in your example *l = 4* and *m = -3*). Also, let *a = (x1,y1)* and *b = (x2,y2)*.

Then it's very easy to show that you need to find *a,b* which minimizes the function `f(l,m) = slm` where `s = sign(x1*x2 + y1*y2)`.

Also, if you have access to non-linear solvers (or you can write your own algorithm since this is a simple function), you can find the solution iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to analyze your code in detail, but what jumps out at me is that the expression in the `min` assignment is different from the expression in the preceding `if`:

```
if(sq((i*a)-(j*c))+sq((i*b)-(j*d))<min)
{
    min=sqrt(sq((i*a)-(j*c)))+sqrt(sq((i*b)-(j*d)));
```

I am pretty sure these two ought to be the same (probably even computed once and stored in a variable).

Also, the assignment of the (floating-point) result of `sqrt()` to an integer variable looks suspect. It might make sense to work with the *square* of the distance, and to avoid `sqrt()` entirely.

Finally, you're only considering linear combinations where the first coefficient is positive and the second is negative. You should consider other possibilities, including those where one of the coefficients is zero.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I thought of too. But couldn't manage to devise an algorithm or implement it into code